# Issue with appcompat v21 Material Design: Fragment overlay content and toolbar

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-appcompat, android-toolbar

I followed http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html to use the toolbar, without fragment, it works perfectly, but when I use fragment, the fragment always overlays the content, and I cannot see toolbar when displaying fragment.

screen:
[image]

and when I starts another activity from the current one, the icon of the toolbar in the new activity doesn't show up. screen:

[image]

I use Android Support Library 21.0.3.

and the code in the MainActivity class:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

    mLeftDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
    mNavigationDrawerAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>( MyActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data);
    mLeftDrawerList.setAdapter(mNavigationDrawerAdapter);

    if (mToolbar != null) {
        mToolbar.setTitle("Home");
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    }
    initDrawer();


    final FragmentManager fragementMgr = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = fragementMgr.beginTransaction();
    transaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, new MyFragment());
    transaction.commit();
}
```

the layout xml:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"     
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- activity view -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />
        <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- navigation drawer -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_gravity="left|start"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:divider="#eee"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

code in MyFragment:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
        final Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Perform action on click
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DetailActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return view;
    }

}
```

layout xml for Fragment:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/hello_fragment"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_gravity="top"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:id="@+id/text"/>
    <Button
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_below="@+id/text"
     android:text="@string/open"
     android:id="@+id/button"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The code in DetailActivity class:
    public class DetailActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.detail_activity);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle("Detail");
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }
}
```

layout for the detail activity:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".DetailActivity">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />
    <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:text="Detail Activity Content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

can anyone help me out? thanks a lot!

Update: I updated the code and layout of the main activity according to reply from m iav.

new screen is blank now with the changes:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so finally after checking the sample: MaterialEverywhere, I came with the solution with updating the layout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"     
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- activity view -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <include 
            android:id="@+id/toolbar" 
            layout="@layout/toolbar" />
        <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
            android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- navigation drawer -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_gravity="left|start"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:divider="#eee"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

the trick is the parent layout of the toolbar and the content frame. Instead of LinearLayout, I use RelativeLayout. and it works now as expected.

anyway, I found such change from the SDK is over complex, with so many changes, and each can cause issues. It will be much better for the developers to have clean APIs with less all these tweaks.

Answer (score 1):

toolbar is a view in your layout , you can see it like textview ,now it is a textview overlay your fragment ,you use attrbibu to below it

Comment: thanks! yes, the solution is pretty much close to this.

Answer (score 0):

This should be your main layout.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"     
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- activity view -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

        <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- navigation drawer -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_gravity="left|start"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:divider="#eee"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And this should be your call to the new fragment:

```
transaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, new MyFragment())
transaction.commit();
```

Regarding your second question, a navigation drawer can't be shared among different activities. You have to use a new Fragment and keep the same Activity you're working in now.

Comment: thanks m iav! I tried your solution, but the fragment doesn't get displayed. the text and the button are not displayed. seems strange. the code I have in activity is:
  transaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, new MyFragment());
  transaction.commit();

Comment: Make sure you have `android:id="@+id/fragment_container"` in the above `FrameLayout`.

Comment: Please update your code in the original question to reflect your changes.

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with your code. My only guess is that you are using `android.app.FragmentManager` instead of `android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager` . Try nesting all four lines, like: `getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(...).commit();`

Comment: HI m iav, actually I did use android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager, otherwise there is compliation error. also you can see the code of above MyActivity, which is the main activity. could it be because of the layout? in the layout of the main activity, the FrameLayout within the LinearLayout has match_parent for layout_height?

Comment: Layouts are OK, except fill_parent that should be switched to match_parent.

Comment: Thanks M iav! actually I managed to change the layout and it solved the problem. I put my solution below.